# How can I determine the difference between false and 0?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a variable which always contains one of these two cases:

- `false`
- A number *(it can be also `0`)*

My variable in reality is this:

```
$index = array_search(1, array_column($var, 'box'));
//=> the output could be something like these: false, 0, 1, 2, ...
```

Now I want to detect `$index` is `false` or anything else. How can I implement such a condition?

It should be noted none of these doesn't work:

```
if ( empty($index) )   { }
if ( !isset($index) )  { }
if ( is_null($index) ) { }
```

And I want this condition:

```
if ( ? ) { // $index is false } else { // $index is a number (even 0) }
```

Comment: `$index !== FALSE`

Comment: @Rizier123 emm, interesting, I thought it will be much harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP identical operator `===`:

```
if (false === 0)
```

This will return `false` if they are of the same type. Unlike `==` where type juggling occurs, `false` is not identical to `0`.

```
if ($index === false) { 
    // $index is false
} else {
    // $index is a number (even 0)
}
```

More information on the difference between the identical operator `===` and the comparison operator `==`: [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)

Answer (score 1):

Use the === operator...

```
if(false == 0)
```

That will cast 0 to false and you get false  == false

```
if(false === 0)
```

That does not cast and you get false compared to zero, which is not the same.

For not equal to, use !== instead of ===

Comment: if false === 0 is always false because you compare a boolean against an integer and it is never the same

Comment: @bub Correct. I was pointing out that false===0 is false while false==0 is true.